# How do I launch zathura from bash/emacs maximized / fullscreen?

Tags: bash, pdf, emacs, fullscreen

I use recently discovered zathura and I like it a lot. I use it now to check the documents from emacs/AUCTeX like:

```
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("zathura" "zathura --page=%(outpage) %o")))
```

Which is the same, for example, as:

```
$ zathura --page=12
```

I would like to launch zathura maximized and / or fullscreen and to page-width zoom.

Is there an option to do that?

Answer (score 3):

`--mode fullscreen`. It isn't in the man file, for whatever reason.

Comment: Do you know how to put it in the `zathurarc` file?

Comment: One thing you could try, if you have `xdg-utils` installed (I think this would probably be a default on Ubuntu) is change your `zathura.desktop` file (probably in ~/.local/share/applications), and add `--mode fullscreen` to the "Exec" line. This means that you're going to have to use `xdg-open` setting the application/pdf mime default to zathura, instead of zathura as-is. And being as hacky a solution as it is, I don't think it'll work well for what you're going for.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for a place to put that line in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Zathura documentation [HERE](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/documentation/) says this:

“The customization of zathura is managed via a configuration file called zathurarc.”

The documentation is extensive and if you know how to edit the configuration file, you should be in good shape… And, yes, you can have it open maximized and set to page width.

Comment: Have you found the command for maximizing the window? I just found window-height and window-width so far.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I saw “fullscreen” but it was under mapping shortcut keys not opening arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I put this alias in my ~/.bashrc to make zathura always open in full screen
mode:

```
    alias zathura='zathura --mode fullscreen'
```